# Coreldraw effect from free programs?

Tags: photo-editing, image-processing

I used to do an effect in CorelDraw that converted an image to a bitmap. The way it did it was group similar colors together into one color chunk giving it a cool effect that looked kind of like this:

[image: bitmapped image]

However, the CorelDraw program I used is no longer supported, and I cant afford to buy a new license just for this effect. Is there another free tool that can do this (preferably on my Linux computer but I can do it on Windows too)?

**Edited Note:** while I understand that the information provided in this question was minimal, and more would have been ideal, I genuinely gave *all* the information I knew, and I am missing the vocabulary in this topic to fully explain what I was looming for. Thank you for your understanding. I did get the answers I was looking for.

Comment: This isn't necessarily off-topic here, but perhaps might get better traction at [graphicdesign.se]. The effect you're talking about doesn't really have a photographic context or application normally. Thus, I'd expect fewer people here to know about the effect, than actual graphic designers over at GDSE.

Comment: What version of Corel Draw are you using?

Comment: I was using a very old one, version 8 maybe? Around 2014, no Windows 10 support.

Comment: You say that the effect looks "kind like this". Does that mean that the effect you want isn't *exactly* demonstrated by this example? In any case, can you please describe the effect you want more precisely?

Comment: You might search for the term "image segmentation". I've seen effects that look like that in image processing when implementing image segmentation algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks it is a byproduct of vectorization.

Vectorization makes some "blobs" of flat colors. In this case the posterization the other answer points to, is one step.

The second step could be finding the edges between this blobs of color and adding a small white color to simulate a **gap between the blobs**.

But you can also try inscape, which is a real vector based program, and vectorize inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Reducing the color palette is "Posterization". Gimp will do this on Linux.

**EDIT**

Your sample is very small to use as a reference. Images are already bitmaps so there is no "converting to a bitmap".

Here is a quick grab of an old image I posterized in GIMP on Linux. If this is not what you are asking for then I'll need more information.

**Full Color**

[image: Sample]

**Posterize to 8 colors**
[image: Posterize-8]

**Posterize to 4 colors**
[image: Posterize-4]

**Posterize to 3 colors**
[image: Posterize-3]

**Posterize to 2 colors**
[image: Posterize-2]

**Edit #2**

From the discussion, it sounds like you actually started with a vector drawing and colored and converted it to a raster or bitmap drawing.

Since Corel is what you were using and lost, you may want to try their free trial [CorelDraw](https://www.coreldraw.com/en/free-trials/?topNav=en) to determine what exactly you are looking to do.

Comment: hi there, the "Posterization" effect in Gimp did not seem to have an effect like this. It did not create chunks of the same color, it just reduced the amount of colors used. If you look at the example I gave you will see a difference.

Comment: @MarkDeven It helps get better answers if you can describe the specific effect you are looking for in words. What one person sees might not be the same as another.

Comment: I added some posterization samples. If this is not what you're asking then I don't understand.

Comment: It looks like GIMP doesn't know how to count. The 2 color image is actually 2 colors *per channel*, or 8 altogether. I assume the higher numbers are similar.

Comment: Yes, I described it incorrectly.

Comment: I’m not sure how else to explain it. The picture I gave an example of was a picture, I’m looking for the effect you can see on it.

Comment: I image that "to a bitmap" means "to a 256-color Windows BMP file" given the age of Coreldraw's heyday

Comment: @Mark I can see a number of effects. I see part of the image in grayscale and part with color. That color is a weird palette (I might say "puke rainbow"). And there seems to be some blotchy camouflage thing going on. Possibly the effect you want includes all of these things? Maybe something else? It's hard for us to guess!

Comment: Those were the actual colors of things, and there was no camouflage, it grouped the shadowing and made depth with different colors.

Comment: The problem is I can’t produce more images and a before and after because I’ve lost Cornell draw.

Answer (score 2):

Try GIMP + G'MIC filter - some effects look similar to your example:

**Artistic / Vector Painting**

[image: Vector Painting effect]

**Artistic / Posterize** (it is not the GIMP built-in Posterize!)

[image: Posterize effect]

**Contours / Segmentation**

[image]

Comment: Messing with that got a similar effect thank you.